# Permanent PivotTable filter

Tags: pivot-table, microsoft-excel-365

Is there a way to make a PivotTable filter permanent?

I.e., prevent or discourage users from removing a filter from a PivotTable, since bringing in that intentionally excluded data would cause confusion.

---

The data source is a Microsoft Query Connection to an Oracle database. So in theory, I could add a filter to the query's SQL WHERE clause. That would work, but in this case, the connection is multi-purpose in this Excel workbook. So I don't want to pre-filter the connection, because I need the excluded data elsewhere in the workbook. So I would need to create an additional connection that includes the excluded data, adding clutter to an already complex workbook. And violating the DRY principle.

Comment: Do you want to allow using other filters? Excel has some options to lock the whole table, but not a specific filter. I found someone using a macro to remove and re-add the filter whenever it gets changed, but it's awkward: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-forum/vba-macros/prevent-pivot-table-filtering

Comment: I'd say current best practice is to pull your main query into separate filtered data models, and use those as your pivot table's source. It's handy for trimming data sources that would have hundreds of fields otherwise

Answer (score 1):

To hide all references to the filters in a Dynamic Table, thus achieving your desired result, complete the following steps:

1. **Right-click** on the Dynamic Table and go to **Options**
2. Go to the **Display** tab
3. Uncheck the option that says **Display Field Captions and Filter Drop Downs**
4. (Optional) You can also uncheck **Show Expand/Collapse Buttons**

Note that this procedure will hide all filters from showing, and the end user will not be able to know that some data is hidden.